# Android and Facebook SDK: share a user-generated photo that clicks out

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm relying on Android's Facebook SDK 4.0 to allow users to share photos on the Facebook graph. I'd like the photos the users share to be clickable so their friends can click through to the app (it's not a photo app, the photos act as lead generators for other user-generated content).

However, it looks like the SDK makes me choose between attaching user-generated photos as bitmaps that are not clickable, or providing an og:url tag to an image URL which IS clickable.

That means I have to set up a photo storage protocol if I want my users' photos to be clickable - am I right? Is there another solution I'm not seeing?

Comment: Please edit your question and illustrate it using screen shots. That would clarify a lot. If you are concerned about app attribution, you should know that all content created from an app using the SDKs or Graph API will have an attribution link next to the timestamp of the content in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is the user-generated photos don't click out. They stay on Facebook and are better featured in the Facebook UI.

On the other hand, when a photo (even if it was generated by the user) is not flagged as user-generated, the Facebook API automatically adds clickability to the og:url reference.